# Remove unnamed rows and rows that contain a certain value in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to remove any unnamed columns and remove rows that contain a specific value:

data

```
    Unamed  ID  Name
0   0       a   app23
1   1       b   db23
2   2       c   db233
```

desired

```
    ID  Name

    b   db23
    c   db233
```

I would like to remove any unnamed columns as well as remove any rows where the Name column values contain the string 'app'

doing

```
df.drop(df.index[df['Name'] == 'app'
```

Any suggestions are helpful

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: [Include your minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Where exactly are you having trouble with the filtering and drops as given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str. contains to identify and drop any row with `app'. The use either drop columns or the iloc or loc accessor to select the rows and chain drop index method.

```
 df[~df['Name'].str.contains('app')].drop(columns=['Unamed']).style.hide_index()
```